# Forced initialization of global variable in function

Tags: c, global-variables

I'm writing a simple game using c, but global variables do not work 
Please take a look at the code below

global variable

```
int board[ROW][COL];
int count[8];
int playerswitch = 1;
```

main

```
int main(void) 
{
    init_board();  //board initialization
    play_tictactoe();
}
```

play_tictactoe

```
void play_tictactoe(void) 
{
    int col, row;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("player %d. Enter rows and columns to place stones: ", playerswitch);
        scanf_s("%d %d", &row, &col);

        if (playerswitch == 1)
        {
            if (put_stone(player1, row - 1, col - 1) != TRUE)
            {
                printf("Put again \n");
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                display_board();
                if (check_win(player1, row - 1, col - 1) == TRUE)
                    break;

                playerswitch = 2;
                continue;
            }
        }
        else if (playerswitch == 2)
        {
            if (put_stone(player2, row - 1, col - 1) != TRUE)
            {
                printf("Put again \n");
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                display_board();
                if (check_win(player2, row - 1, col - 1) == TRUE)
                    break;

                playerswitch = 1;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGW6f.png)

The first time I entered a value in the global variable 2-D array, the output was correct, but the second time I entered it, the global variable 2-D array was forced to initialize, so the value I entered was lost. And once again, the second entry will appear correctly on the third entry. Why is this?
I tried debugging and it was initialized by check_win function, but I do not know why.

check_win

```
int check_win(int player, int checkRow, int checkCol)
{
    int check, row, col;
    count[8] =  0;

    row = checkRow;
    col = checkCol;

    while(row>=0 || col>=0)
    {
        if (board[row][col] != player)
                return FALSE;

        count[0]++;
        row--;
        col--;
    }

    row = checkRow;
    col = checkCol;

    while (row < ROW || col < COL)
    {
        if (board[row][col] != player)
            return FALSE;

        count[1]++;
        row++;
        col++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if (count[i] == 5)
            return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need global variables for your purpose, you should avoid them as long as you don't need them!

Comment: _the global variable 2-D array was forced to initialize_ What does this mean? Who forces what?

Comment: `count[8] = 0;` This writes out of bounds and invokes _undefined behaviour_

Comment: Where are `put_stone` and `display_board`?

Comment: @Gerhardh thank you problem fix

Comment: As mentioned by @Silveris, I'd like to add that you should not use global variables as long as you don't need them as it'd become a debugging nightmare as your program grows. You wouldn't know where it'd have been modified and would lost countless amount of time on debugging.